# Are Visual C++ 2013 binaries compatible with Visual C++ 2017 binaries?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

In one of our C++ solutions, we use 3rd part libraries. These libraries are compatible to VS 2013. Now we are migrating our solution to VS 2017 and found that some of the 3rd party libraries do not have VS 2017 compatible versions.

So we tried to use some of the VS2013 compatible libraries in VS20173 and the tried API calls work fine.

Can I assume that the libraries work with VS 2017 executable without any issues?

Comment: The answer is no for C++ libraries. C libraries are likely to work. I'll wait for somebody to prove me wrong.

Comment: The APIs are exported as functions and not C++ classes

Comment: Name mangling happens even for non-member functions.

Comment: It all depends how thoroughly the programmer avoided taking a dependency on the runtime library in his api.  Not so easy to do in C++, throwing an std::exception or using, say, std::string as an argument or return value ruins it.  Talk to him about it.

Comment: If they export C-style API then they are compatible. Note that "C-Style API" means not just "APIs are exported as functions and not C++ classes", but all functions being "extern C", using only C types as arguments / return values and not throwing.

Comment: @VTT - The functions are marked with extern C. I will check the API parameters and return types in detail

Comment: @VTT no, in general they are not. They have different runtime DLLs to begin with, and if you create something simple like FILE* in your app compiled with VC++2017 and pass it down to your old library, there is no guarantee it will work.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I guess I should've written "built-in" C types. But it is too late to edit that comment...

Comment: @VTT what's biggest change in 2015 wrt 2013 is this, IMHO: "Refactored binaries The CRT Library has been refactored into a two different binaries, a Universal CRT (ucrtbase), which contains most of the standard functionality, and a VC Runtime Library (vcruntime), which contains the compiler-related functionality, such as exception handling, and intrinsics." I, frankly, cannot contemplate shipping product depending on two incompatible runtimes and crossing fingers for it to work. See link in my answer for details

Comment: Just to add to some of the other comments: watch out for memory management.  You can't allocate using one runtime support and deallocate in the other.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Actually it not really possible to avoid depending on multiple runtimes. Even If your own executable and libraries are built with the same toolset and setting there will also be Windows NT CRT present. And more sophisticated applications could use dozens of other runtimes from completely different compilers. But there will be no problem as long as they are properly isolated and interop only though a C-Style API.

Comment: @VTT: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "NT CRT". The CRT part that ships as part of the Windows API is the Universal CRT. The CRT which was part of Windows NT implementation (but not its API) was a fork of the MSVC6 CRT, and that fork evolved as Windows evolved. And in fact they can also interop via other mechanisms besides a  C-style API, the other common choice is a COM style API.

Comment: @MSalters "Windows NT CRT" is a library description for C runtime dll internally used by Windows (Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll) which get loaded into every process and can exists peacefully along with application-specific runtime libraries. Also COM style API is a variation of C-style API.

Answer (score 4):

In general - no. AFAIK, VC++2015 (aka toolset v140) and VC++2017 (aka toolset v141) are stated to be binary compatible. No such statement were made wrt VC++2013, and I believe there are breaking changes (like sizeof(list) etc).

It might work, but could lead to hard-to-debug problem

Microsoft statement:

"A more-severe kind of change, the breaking change can affect binary compatibility, but these kinds of binary compatibility breaks only occur between major versions of Visual Studio. For example, between Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015."

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/visual-cpp-change-history-2003-2015

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is guaranteed but binary compatibility of Visual C++ compilers is generally better than officially announced. Just make sure you do not create/destroy object across different runtimes, propagate exceptions and do not pass STL related objects as parameters.

If the third party libraries expose C style interfaces and they are compiled as DLLs the task is even easier. So you should review those interfaces and verify how much they vary from the general interoperability guidelines.